# Cannot display selected data (telno) from database using PHP, HTML and SQL

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I'm a newbie in PHP; please guide me slowly and carefully.

I have a login page (login.php) and a user page (useracc-test.php). The user page (useracc-test.php) displays all personal data after a user logs in using his own username and password. I can display other data such as (name), (username) and (telno) in php script when I echo it.

But the problem is, when I tried to echo the data in html, just below the php script, only (username) shows on the screen. The other two (name) and (telno) show nothing. No errors displayed on browser also, and also no syntax error. Below is my user page (useracc-test.php).

```
   <?php

//useracc-test.php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();


 /**
 * Include our MySQL connection.
 */
// require 'lib/password.php';
require 'connect-test.php';
$userName=$_POST['username'];






//$sql = "SELECT name, username FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
//$result = $conn->query($sql);
$query = sprintf("select name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($userName));


$result = $conn->query($query); ?>



<?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()): ?>

<div id="satu"><?= $row['name'] ?></div>
<div id="dua"><?= $row['username'] ?></div>
<div id="tiga"><?= $row['telno'] ?></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>







<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 51px;
    top: 238px;
    width: 237px;
    height: 93px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 344px;
    width: 234px;
    height: 104px;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="apDiv2"><span class="error"><?php echo $userName; ?></span></div>
<div id="apDiv1"><span class="error"><?php echo $row['telno'] ?></span></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Last html code should be

```
<html>
<head>
.....
</head>

<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**You have put `</head>` in `<body>` section.**

If the database connection is OK, also try changing

```
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
```

To

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

And add

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at above in php file.
However, this doesn't make PHP show parse errors - the only way to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:

```
display_errors = on
```

And check for errors.

Comment: Hi Dr Manish Joshi...I never expected to see a doctor in the house..btw thanks for the reply..but can you show me the error..I don't quite understand what you mean....

Comment: Hi Dr Manish Joshi..i Already corrected the </head>  as below:<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv2 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 51px;
 top: 238px;
 width: 237px;
 height: 93px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#apDiv1 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50px;
 top: 344px;
 width: 234px;
 height: 104px;
 z-index: 2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="apDiv2"><span class="error"><?php echo $userName; ?></span></div>
<div id="apDiv1"><span class="error"><?php echo $row['telno'] ?></span></div>
<title> </title>

</body>
</html>


but problem still the same..cannot display "telno" in html.

Comment: <div id="apDiv1"><span class="error"><?php echo $row['telno'] ?></span></div> does not show up on the Internet...

Comment: ok...as it is showing $username, and $username = $_POST['username'], it is taking $username from session and not from database....so please check for column names, tablename etc keenly in your $query...

Comment: hi Dr Manish Joshi..I already did like this.. while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: But I got error :Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 30

Comment: Is there another way..where I don't need to use HTML  to echo the result.because it keeps giving errors..instead of echoing the result in HTML(which is not working)...since. my PHP is working.. I can echo from there (hwo do I put those result in div tag layers??) where I can move and adjust the results easily to the left, right or center of the page..

Comment: while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{ 
?>
<div id="satu"> <?php echo $row['name'] ;  ?> </div>


<div id="dua"><?php echo $row['username']; ?> </div>
<div id="tiga"><?php echo $row['telno'];  }



?

Comment: How do I put <?php echo $row['name'] ; ?>inside a div tag layer..so i can move it around easily on the page since the HTML keeps giving errors..tq for your patient...Im very sorry and I apologise.. I hope Im not troubling u.. I really want to learn..

Comment: are you using mysqli in connect-test.php? try replacing while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) to while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: Hi Dr Manish Joshi...tq for ur reply..yes Im using mysqli..I already did what u told me.. this time no error..but  "telno" is not displayed on screen..<?php echo $row['telno'] ?> in HTML section suppose to be displayed...but still nothing on the screen..:-(

Comment: ok.. confirm column name for tel number in database...is it "telno" or else ? are name and username now displayed?

Comment: in the PHP while section...all of them are displayed on screen.. but in the HTML..my telno is not displayed.(.yes..telno is my column name in database..confirm.. )

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by member of Stack Overflow just now. Regarding div tags which I posted previously, and the problem was a 2 in 1 coincidently. The person managed to solve everything, the person's name was Svdb.

Below is the code solved by him:

```
<body>
<div id="apDiv2"><span class="error"><?php echo $userName; ?></span></div>
<div id="apDiv1"><span class="error"><?php echo $row['telno'] ?></span></div>

<?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()): ?>

<div id="satu"><?= $row['name'] ?></div>
<div id="dua"><?= $row['username'] ?></div>
<div id="tiga"><?= $row['telno'] ?></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</body>
</html>
```